# Averaging 4 identical arrays cell to cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab, average

I have four arrays of the same dimensions: (10,000, 1). My goal is to  average the four arrays into one that has the same dimensions. How can one achieve it the most efficient way?

Edit: Over a year later, the silliness of this question is very apparent. Thank you for those who helped pry off the training wheels. In the immortal words 'Read the documentation!' I trust

Comment: If your arrays are e.g. w,x,y,z , why cannot you just do avg = (w + x + y + z ) /4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add each array and divide by 4. 
Example : arrays A1 A2 A3 A4
Average = (A1 + A2 + A3 + A4)/4
Since the arrays are identical in size, MATLAB will automatically add corresponding elements in the array and provide the accurate result.
Is there another problem you are having with this ?

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help

Comment: @tekkkkkkk Hi please "accept" this answer if this solved your problem.